# Absent minOccurs attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

My question is simple: If an element definition in an XSD lacks the minOccurs attribute does that mean that the element is omittable?

for exmaple:

```
<!-- language: xsd -->
<xs:element name="kezdo_ido" type="xs:date">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Az exportálással érintett időszak kezdő dátuma.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Can I omit the element ?

Comment: @Attila Fulop Az bizony :D

Answer (score 4):

No, it means that the element is obligatory.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints):

> The default value for both the minOccurs and the maxOccurs attributes
>   is 1.

Answer (score 1):

The contrary is true: an absent `minOccurs` attribute implies `minOccurs='1'`